# How to read parameters from console assembly

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly

I'm trying to read parameters from console in Assembly, I already read the number of parameters but I can't read the next lines.

I tried to do:

```
pop     ebp
mov     [opcion], ebp
push    opcion
call    printf
```

But show me nothing.
And when I try:

```
pop     ebp
mov     [opcion], ebp
mov     eax, opcion
call    print
```

It show me: �ĉ�

This is the code where I'm reading the number of parameters and where I'm trying to print the parameters that the user sends to the program.

```
SECTION     .bss
n1:     resb    255
opcion:         resb    255
SECTION     .text
global main
main:
    call    clear
    pop     ebp
    pop     ebp         ;Number of parameters
    mov     ecx, ebp
    cmp     ecx, 2
    jl  interseccionCasos
    je  primerCaso
    call    quit
primerCaso:
    pop     ebp
    mov     [opcion], ebp
    push    opcion
    call    printf
    call    quit
    ret
```

The name of the application is rpn, so when I run the code with 5 as parameter like './rpn 2' the output should be 2 or if I send the parameters "5 + 28" like './rpn "5 + 28"' the output should be "5 + 28"

I am using the gcc compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to main is “argv”, which is the address of an array of pointers to strings. You are using the second parameter as if it a string itself.

To fix this, in primerCaso, put:

```
pop ebp 
mov ebp, [ebp+4]
push ebp 
call printf
```

Comment: Note, I don’t recommend using a parameter as directly as the printf format. Use “%s\n” for the format, and pass the string as the second parameter to printf.

Comment: When I do it, shows me an error that says 
rpn.asm:31: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
I tried to use:
<code>
pop  ebp 
push  dword [ebp + 4]
call  printf
</code>
But show me nothing.

Comment: Please add any additional info and your changes into your original question by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55906260/edit) link. I.e. show both the code you try and the error you get next to each other.